# I extended some functionality in the slick module, but I am looking to do it in a way that doesn't get erased each time I update slick

Tags: 8, updating

I extended some functionality in the slick module, but I am looking to do it in a way that doesn't get erased each time I update slick.

I added a css file and edited the slick skin php file to use the css file depending on the user's choice. I also added a bootstrap class to the slick.html.twig template so that the slider would disappear on mobile devices.

Should I make a custom module that acts like slick_examples?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In my opinion, the easiest way to preserve changes to contributed code is to manage your dependencies through [Composer](https://www.drupal.org/docs/develop/local-server-setup/linux-development-environments/set-up-a-local-development-drupal-0-3#s-composer-includes-also-curl) and use [patches](https://groups.drupal.org/node/518975). When you update slick in the future, the output of the command will directly tell you which of your patches have been broken by the update.

Answer (score 0):

As far a I can tell from your description of the changes you've made, you should be able to implement all of these in a custom module.

- Adding a css file: just add them as a library in your custom module, and add them in some HOOK_alter where you check the user preference.
- Overriding the template: it's easiest to do this in your theme, but can be done in the HOOK_theme: https://www.drupal.org/forum/support/module-development-and-code-questions/2015-06-03/drupal-8-override-template-with

That should save you the trouble of patching existing modules.

Answer (score -1):

i thought that you can override or extend controllers or plugin, its the only way to preserve the changes after updates

Comment: yep but also patches via composer

Comment: Hi  @Ahmed Matri and welcome to Drupal Answers. While your answer is not bad, it's too short and it's more a comment than a proper answer explaining the solution and why it's a good choice for the OP.